# XSL / XPath expression to check if a node contains at least one non-empty child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to check if an XML node has at least one non-empty child. Applied to this XML the expression should return `true`

```
<xml>
    <node>
       <node1/>
       <node2/>
       <node3>value</node3>
    </node>
</xml>
```

I tried to use this expression: `<xsl:if test="not(/xml/node/child::* = '')">` but it seems to check if **all** children are not empty.

How can I write an expression which returns `true` if **at least one** element is not empty? Is there a way to do this without creating another template to iterate over node chldren?

**UPD:** I'm thinking of counting non-empty nodes like
`test="count(not(/xml/node/child::* = '')) &gt; '0'"`
but somehow just can't make it work right. This expression is not a well-formed one.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**More accurate, simpler and more efficient (no need to use the `count()` function)**:

```
  /*/node/*[text()]
```

**If you want to exclude any element that has only whitespace-only text children, use:**

```
  /*/node/*[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I could test for "if not a single grandchild `term` (no matter what the parent element is called) contains the string `','`"? I tried `record[not(contains(*/*/term, ','))]`, but it matched records in which the first `term` had no `','`, and the second did (seems to logically miss the *any* / *none* aspect).

Comment: Sir, +1 for nice Xpath Expression.

Answer (score 12):

You just need `<xsl:if test="/xml/node/* != ''" />`.

In XPath an `=` or `!=` comparison where one side is a node set and the other side is a string succeeds if *any* of the nodes in the set passes the comparison.  Thus

```
not(x = '')
```

means "it is not the case that any `x` child element of the current node has an empty string value", which is fundamentally different from

```
x != ''
```

which means "at least one `x` child element of the current node has a string value that is not empty".  In particular, if you want to check that *all* `x` children are empty, you need to use a "double-negative" test

```
not(x != '')
```

Comment: That's one of those invaluable pieces of programming knowledge that will save you hours of stress.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one XPath that should accomplish the job:

```
count(/*/node/*[text()]) &gt; 0
```

**When used in a sample XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/node/*[text()]) &gt; 0" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...which is, in turn, applied to the provided example XML:**

```
<xml>
  <node>
    <node1/>
    <node2/>
    <node3>value</node3>
  </node>
</xml>
```

**...the expected result is produced:**

```
true
```

**If we apply the same XSLT against a simply modified XML:**

```
<xml>
  <node>
    <node1/>
    <node2/>
    <node3/>
  </node>
</xml>
```

**...again, the expected result is produced:**

```
false
```

**Explanation:**

The XPath used searches for all children of a `<node>` element (which are, in turn, children of the root element) that have a non-empty text value (as specified by `text()`); should the count of such `<node>` children be greater than 0, then the XPath resolves to `true`.

Comment: Oh, `text()`.. I knew I missed something! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/*/node/*[string-length(text()) &gt;0]!=''"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**
This will find the first node with a string length greater than zero and then compares such node contents with empty string (the comparison will return the existence of a non-empty string node); this code can also be used to look for a specific criteria in any node, for example identify the existence of a node which contains specific string or starts with some character or any other condition; please use this as the inner condition of the node reference for the code to work its magic.