# How to find empty elements in xml using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I am searching empty xml tag. For e.g.,

```
  <employee>
     <name></name>
  </employee>
  <employee>
      <name>abc</name>
   </employee>
```

Here how to find empty tag(name tag) using Node.js?

Comment: Could you use XPath? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703478/xsl-xpath-expression-to-check-if-a-node-contains-at-least-one-non-empty-child

Answer (score 1):

You have to traverse through all the relevant tags and check their content. If the content is found to be null then the tag is empty. Below is a piece of code to help you along the way.

```
  var emptytext=txtElement[0].childNodes[0];
  if(emptytext===null)
  {
     alert("Text is empty");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  The answer is basically a transplant of the answer that the OP put in his question; see the edit history.

Comment: Oh dear. Sorry, I didn't see that.