# Using XSLT, how to remove the empty element, which does not have an attribute or data, in an XML document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We want to remove empty Tag that is CommentLine from XML

```
<CommentLine/>
```

INPUT XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
  <Orders>   
    <OrderHeader>  
      <CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>  
    </OrderHeader>   
    <OrderDetails>   
      <CommentLine>
        <Comment>Ensure saddle is color coded</Comment>  
        <OrderLineID>OR-1810127</OrderLineID>  
      </CommentLine>  
      <CommentLine>
        <Comment>EDI-001</Comment>  
        <OrderLineID>OR-1810128</OrderLineID>  
      </CommentLine>  
      <StockLine>  
        <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>  
        <StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode> 
        <StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>  
        <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty>
      </StockLine>  
      <CommentLine>
        <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>  
        <OrderLineID>OR-1810124</OrderLineID>  
      </CommentLine>   
      <CommentLine>  
        <Comment>EDI-SAVE</Comment> 
        <OrderLineID>OR-1810125</OrderLineID>  
      </CommentLine>

      <CommentLine/>

    </OrderDetails>  
  </Orders>  
</SalesOrders>
```

Tried XML on it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>  -<SalesOrders xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SDOC.XSD" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   
            -<Orders>   
            -<OrderHeader>  
            <CustomerPoNumber>AB-54354</CustomerPoNumber>  
            </OrderHeader>   
            -<OrderDetails>   
            -<CommentLine>  <Comment>Ensure saddle is color coded</Comment>  
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810127</OrderLineID>  

            </CommentLine>  
            -<CommentLine>  <Comment>EDI-001</Comment>  
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810128</OrderLineID>  
            </CommentLine>  
            -<StockLine>  
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>  
            <StockCode>ABSH-SMH-12OZ-01</StockCode> 
             <StockDescription>SMH ABS BALANCE SHAMPOO 12OZ</StockDescription>  
            <OrderQty>1.0</OrderQty> </StockLine>  
             -<CommentLine>  <Comment>This is for test purpose</Comment>  
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810124</OrderLineID>  
            </CommentLine>   
            -<CommentLine>  
            <Comment>EDI-SAVE</Comment> 
             <OrderLineID>OR-1810125</OrderLineID>  
            </CommentLine>  

            </OrderDetails>  
            </Orders>  
            </SalesOrders>
```

we have to remove  element in complete Input XML.

Any help would be much appreciated ! Thanks for valuable time.

Comment: Related: [How to tell using xpath if an element is present and non empty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15909348/205233) and [XSL / XPath expression to check if a node contains at least one non-empty child](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13703478/205233).

Comment: Try `match="node()[.='']"` instead of `match="@xsi:nil[.='true']"`

Comment: ps. looking at the answers on @Filburt's links there's one crucial difference between how they behave compared to my note above; that is in handling elements containing only empty elements: e.g. `<OrderDetails><CommentLine/></OrderDetails>`.  Decide how you want it to behave in that scenario then compare the answers presented with this test data to see what fits (i.e. mine would preserve the empty OrderDetails element; others wouldn't).  That could also be addressed by adding other filters (e.g. targeting only elements called `CommentLine`).

Comment: @JohnLBevan I tried the same as  you suggested . But it did not worked for me.

Comment: It is not removing <CommentLine/>

Comment: Interesting; what XSLT engine are you using?  http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQgq

Comment: ps. regarding my comment about mine leaving empty parent elements; that's not true; I think I made a mistake in my testing; not sure what... Will provide an answer which includes that option...

Comment: we are using SAXON .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will remove any empty elements without removing their parent elements (i.e. if you had `<OrderDetails><CommentLine/></OrderDetails>` you'd get and empty `OrderDetails` element in your result set.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()[./node()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i.e. I'm telling the system to only return nodes which have child nodes (be they element or text).
`<xsl:template match="@*|node()[./node()]">`

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYjs

Per @Filburt's comments, if you wanted to also remove elements which become empty once their empty child elements are removed, follow the advise on these links:

- [XSL / XPath expression to check if a node contains at least one non-empty child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703478/xsl-xpath-expression-to-check-if-a-node-contains-at-least-one-non-empty-child)
- [How to tell using XPath if an element is present and non empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909348/how-to-tell-using-xpath-if-an-element-is-present-and-non-empty)

Comment: when i am adding this template getting following error : http://paste.ofcode.org/AibFyqZYNCv4ZHhSmsdDEd  i am also getting duplicate  data for  <commentLine> tag . is that possible to remove duplicate tag  using  xslt 2.0